# How to install TensorFlow Developer version for both Python2 and Python3

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was working on the TensorFlow Dev version, and when running the build tests, I can run them only using Python 2 or Python 3 but not both. Currently I am using a soolution where I have two virtual environments, one for 2 and one for 3. This is inconvenient because whenever I want to test my changes to the TF, I have to migrate those changes to the other environment and run them there separately. This is error prone, and really tedious.

Another approach I have tried before is running either `my_setup_for_python2(...); python setup.py develop` or `my_setup_for_python3(...); python3 setup.py develop`, depending on what I am testing. This is very time consuming, and also not convenient.

I know that TF dev files are linked, and not copied.
The question is if there is a way to follow the instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup#setting_up_tensorflow_for_development) but installing the dev for both python2 and python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Dev files, do you mean install the source code?
You can always rerun

> ./configure

And configure your source to use python3. You cannot tell your source to use both at the same time, but you can switch between different python versions whenever you like using configure. However this will run bazel clean, which will destroy your bazel cache.
To avoid that, you may just comment out the call to bazel_clean_and_fetch in configure script. In r0.12 branch it is here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.12/configure#L146

This can work, however you may also see some issues due to reusing bazel cache.

Comment: The problem is that `configure` + `python setup.py develop` takes pretty long, and that is exactly what I am doing right now. I was looking for a way to avoid it, and avoid having two separate installations as well

Comment: Due to a known bazel bug, configure invalidates the full bazel cache.  That is the cause of the full rebuild. Once that bug is resolved running configure and building should not be as bad. Other than rerunning configure, unfortunately I cannot recommend another solution to be able to run TF with two different python versions in the same repository.

Comment: In that case, do u think it is possible to have a separate folder with soft links pointing to the actual TF subfolders, and running `configure` for python 3 in there?

Comment: Any run to ./configure runs bazel clean --expunge and I think it will invalidate all bazel cache. Just a wild idea, what happens if you comment out this line before you run configure: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/configure#L151 (Disclaimer, I have not tested this myself, so you might see weird issues caused by the azel bug I mentioned above.)

Comment: I am trying to rerun it in a "soft-link" directory, just to test it out, if it doens't work, will try out your suggestion. So far it looks like the bazel cache under `/private/var/tmp/...` is not overriden -- well the setup is still going -- gonna ping back once it is done.

Comment: OK, I get a `ImportError: cannot import name pywrap_tensorflow` error if I try to use a TF directory with symlinks even if I run from outside source directory. Will try the `configure#L151` now

Comment: I ran `configure` on python3 first, and after that I commented out `configure#L151` and `configure#L475`, and ran it again on Python2. So far, both Python2 and Python3 work fine. There might be some unexpected behavior in the future (need to test more). Python3 is in its own virtual environment; the TF directory for Python3 is separate with soft links pointing to the original source (except `_python_build`). You should edit your answer to support that -- I will mark it as resolved :) Tnx!